# How to check if the sides of a circle are going to be drawn outside of the phone

Tags: java, android, canvas

So if you have an app that draws a random circle on an android phone it will draw it x, y anywhere on the screen. Well if your circle has a radius of 200 and is drawn on 0,0. Only half the circle will appear to the user. The other half in cyber space. So how could you test if a circle is being drawn outside the canvas? Here is the method that generates the random x, and y

```
private int[] generateXY() {
        if (theRandom == null) {
            randomWidthOne =(int) (theRandom.nextInt((int) Math.abs(getWidth()-radiusOne/2)) + radiusOne/2f);
            randomHeightOne = (theRandom.nextInt((int)Math.abs((getHeight()-radiusOne/2 + radiusOne/2f))));
        } else {
            randomWidthOne =(int) (theRandom.nextInt((int) Math.abs(getWidth()-radiusOne/2)) + radiusOne/2f);
            randomHeightOne = (theRandom.nextInt((int)Math.abs((getHeight()-radiusOne/2 + radiusOne/2f))));
        }
        return new int[] {randomWidthOne, randomHeightOne};
    }
```

Comment: Do you have instance of that object or have to do just created.?

Comment: its a method not an object

Comment: No, I'm talking about circles.

Answer (score 1):

Let x,y be the center of the circle and r its radius.
Let h be the height of the screen and w the width.
I assume that the lower edge of the screen has a height of y=0,
and the top is  y=h.

```
if(  ((x+radius)>w)  || ((x-radius)<0)  ||  ((y-r)<0) || ((y+r)>h) )
    return true; //circle falls outside the screen
else
    return false;  //the entire circle's are is inside the screen
```